# Multiple foreign key value SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please tell me, is it possible somehow in Postgres to specify an array as a data type that contains foreign key elements
I have next table:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Team
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    idOwnerTeam INT,
    idTeamUsers INT[], -- PROBLEM
    FOREIGN KEY (idOwnerTeam) REFERENCES User(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (idTeamUsers ) REFERENCES User(id) -- PROBLEM
);
```

I will be grateful for any help

I know that this problem can be solved if you specify the command from the user. Then the solution will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    idTeam INT
);

CREATE TABLE Team
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    idOwnerTeam INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idOwnerTeam) REFERENCES User(id),
);

ALTER TABLE User
ADD FOREIGN KEY (idTeam) REFERENCES Team(id);
```

But unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Google for many to many relation. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)  You should have another relation called `UserTeam` which would link users to teams.

Comment: Don't use arrays for that. use a proper many-to-many relationship. Additionally: the use of `serial` is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favour of the standard compliant `identity` columns.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and fix your data model. Don’t use arrays for this, that will cause many issues and this is just the first

Comment: `idTeamUsers INT[], -- PROBLEM` -- Yes, that's not a normalized design, and in fact is not even 1NF. I would strongly recommend to improve the design at least to 3NF. As it is, it looks like a no-sql design.

Comment: "...is it possible somehow in Postgres to specify an array as a data type that contains foreign key elements..."  -- No. You can store them, yes, but they won't act as foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help! Still, I will use an additional table to implement a many-to-many relationship